# persistant sessions?

Tags: firebase

Correct me if im wrong but the auth sessions have a 30day max limit? If that is the case, is there a way to keep my server node app listening to an authenticated dataRef persist forever?

Cheers,
Trav.

Comment: Couldn't you just have it re-auth every few days? Or when the auth fails?

Comment: kato, thanks, seems simple when you say it.  i feel silly for not thinking that before i posted.  cheers.

Comment: Ah, well it always seems easier when you don't grok the convoluted layers and requirements of the app; my daughter comes up with solutions like this all the time. :)

Comment: You can also just set the expiration time to some time in the distant future.

Answer (score 2):

Since the [on method has a cancel callback](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/on.html) that is invoked any time permissions are revoked (i.e. auth expires), here's one (untested) possibility to handle the persistent connection:

```
var fb = new Firebase(URL_AND_PATH);
fb.auth( TOKEN, restart );

function _childAdded(ss) {
   /* do something with data */
}

function _authRevoked() {
   fb.unauth();
   fb.auth( TOKEN, restart );
};

function restart(error) {
   if( error ) { console.error(error); }
   else {
      fb.on('child_added', _childAdded, _authRevoked );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kato's suggestion, what you can do is authenticate by passing in your global Firebase secret (available in Forge -> Auth -> Firebase Secrets -> "Show"). This is to be used only in trusted environments (e.g. your backend server), so be sure to not leak it by checking it in to your source control, passing it over to your client-code/end users, etc. This will only "expire" if the secret is revoked.